# give users dupe-hammer when marking their own questions as a dupe

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I have seen two examples recently ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30732427/how-does-different-execution-paths-differ-from-branch-predication), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714009/how-to-detect-nvidia-cuda-architecture)) where OP came to the realization that *their own question* was a duplicate of another, and chose to vote-to-close their own question as a duplicate of another.

It seems indisputable in these cases that their judgment in the matter should be accepted, and should not require another set of users, or a gold-hammer user, or Community to come along and close the loop.

I propose that if a user votes-to-close **their own question** as a duplicate, that closure vote should take effect immediately, and not require other mechanisms to actually close the question as a dupe.

Comment: Doesn't that already happen? At least, if another person suggests a duplicate the OP can agree and it will be instantly closed.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/250981/new-ui-encourages-askers-to-confirm-or-dispute-duplicate-votes

Comment: You can actually see the current process in action in your first link- See where it says it was closed by "Community"? Hover over that. You'll see "This question's author approved a pending duplicate vote."

Comment: It certainly did not happen in [this case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30714009/how-to-detect-nvidia-cuda-architecture).  The OP voted to close, and the question simply had close votes.  Then I came along and voted to close and it was then, at that point, closed.  The other case I reference is less clear to me, as I am not sure what the community behavior was there.  My own vote on that question was not a dupe but "unclear what you are asking" but SO lumps that in with the close vote description that finally gets applied to the question.

Comment: Makes sense on the surface, if only we'd trust the OP to be the most trustworthy authority on how to properly resolve the Q+A.  We don't.

Comment: @HansPassant We sorta do in this case.  the OP can cast a binding duplication close vote on their own questions.

Comment: I agree that any given OP is not completely trusted to resolve all Q+A processes.  However, for the specific example here, when an OP is marking their own question as a dupe, I think it's sensible.  And, based on my lack of understanding as illuminated by the answers, it appears that we (essentially) *already do trust the OP* in this specific case.

Comment: This is getting awfully mixed up.  There's a world of difference between the OP dup-closing by himself versus him agreeing to *somebody else's* dup vote.  The OP is already in control to a large degree, he can delete the question when nobody has answered it yet.  Which I personally favor, all these link traps are very bad Google juice.

Comment: Awful lot of duplicate questions asked by users who we explicitly DO NOT trust to either flag or vote to close, @Robert. The current mechanism still works for them, and works the same way for those we do trust to some extent. I rather doubt that introducing a different mechanism would improve matters much, while an actual binding OP vote would remove the ability for askers to retract their own vote if they made a mistake.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If a user believes their post is a duplicate, they can agree.  If they *refresh the page*, they get a banner at the top of there post that alerts them that the question was marked as a duplicate and asks if the duplicate target solves the problem.  If the OP clicks the button <kbd>That solved my problem!</kbd> then the Community♦ user will apply the duplication.

[image: This question's author approved a pending duplicate vote.]

If you look at the first post, it has the Community♦ user on it, and that tells you the OP thought the duplicate flag was correct.  This automatically closes the question and bypasses the rules of how many people need to vote to close a question.

Comment: Sort of weird that the UI would ask them "does this solve your problem?". "Well yeah, that's why I voted to close it!"

Comment: @gunr2171 I think it is serving up the same thing regardless if they flagged it or someone else.

Comment: Then let's not go through the rigamarole of requiring the user to refresh the page and then accept their own vote that they just voted.

Comment: @RobertCrovella That would be nice that if the OP votes to close that it should just close the question.

Comment: Thanks for the answers.  Mostly this question was based on my lack of understanding - there already is a short-circuited mechanism to rapidly accept the OP's vote in this case.  I think it could perhaps be improved slightly but that is probably a nit. (And apparently not widely agreed to...)

Answer (score 11):

When a question is marked as duplicate, the OP gets a notification asking them whether they agree that their question is a duplicate. If they do agree, then the Community user will close the question as duplicate. This is better than letting the OP vote because Community is a diamond-moderator and has a binding vote (which closes the question immediately). A great deal of OPs cannot vote to close at all, or can only vote with normal votes, and thus would require still more votes from other users.

It was indeed *immensely* frustrating in the past before this feature was implemented when OPs would agree that their question was a duplicate but it would still take votes to close it.