# What was the route to my question being closed as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, flags, close-reasons

I asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31701549/903011), [Val](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4604579/val) commented that it is possibly a duplicate (which, I believe, is some kind of automated comment after flagging it as duplicate (?) (because I often see the same exact wording)).

I agree, this is a good duplicate and [after some research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265737/903011) I decided to keep it instead of deleting it.

In order to speed up the "close as duplicated" process I flagged my own question as duplicate and was told that four more flags are needed to finally close it (I think it was four).

Right after that my question got, next to the title, a frame asking me if the duplicate is a true one, to which I answered yes and the question was closed immediately.

This is exactly what I wanted to happen, I am surprised, though, that `Community` closed the question (which means that there is an automated process behind).

My question (out of curiosity) is: what is the workflow which was triggered in that case? Is this the fact that I flagged my own question as duplicate? (=that made the box appear, which is a good idea)

Comment: since you said "yes", community is "you" actually ;) whenever your posts get flagged as dupes, you will receive the box saying "is this helping?" and if you say yes, community handles the dupe for you

Comment: Possible dupe:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/296481/1079354

Comment: so that was triggered after the first "vote to close", right? (which "vote to close" happened to be mine). In that case Val's comment was a true (handwritten so to speak) comment and not something automated (I am asking as I see the exact same wording very often and I am not sure if everybody uses the same terms or if this is something which appears automatically (which I seem to recall having read once on meta))

Comment: OK, this (meta) question is a duplicate, I do see the box, which I will accept (as it is - indeed - a duplicate:)).

Comment: @WoJ when you flag or "closevote" for dupe, you will indeed send an automated comment. Some people copied that comment and use it as a canned comment, so it's possible that the comment from val was NOT an actual vote, indeed.